# Double Y-Axis Sometimes Both on Left

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I've developed a chart for my paper: https://www.writelatex.com/502050hhmmqs

As you can see, there are two y-axes, with their labels correctly placed on opposite sides of the chart.  However, when I go to use it in my paper, I get the labels overlapping:

[image: Overlapping y-axes]

The only difference I can think of is that the document class is somewhat different, but I don't know how that would affect this, nor how to fix it.

Aside: I'd also like to get rid of all spacing between bars within a bar group.

Comment: Are you perhaps using different version of PGFPlots? It's usually a good idea not to set `compat=newest`, but `compat=<whatever version you're using>`. That way, you'll get an error if the version on a different machine doesn't match, and your graph will look the same even with newer versions of PGFPlots.

Comment: To get rid of the gaps, set `ybar=\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks; it seems to make it better.  At certain zooms (not necessarily higher), however, I can see gaps.

Comment: Try `ybar=0pt`.

Comment: With this, I was unable to find spaces between bars at any zoom I tried.  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), Section 2.2 "Upgrade remarks" carefully. It is recommended that you use the `compat` key with the **lowest** version number that suits your needs. Generally, it should be always at least `1.3` and it is not recommended to use `newest`. A document with `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` is not portable - it may look different than expected when compiled on a system with another `pgfplots` version.

Comment: That line was from an example.  I changed it to read 1.3, which made both renders look as expected.  Thanks,